# Random Image button leads to new html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a random image button and everytime I click it, it ends up randomizing the pictures in a new blank html page. Not the current html page I'm in.

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" src =  "page3.js">

             function randomImg1() {
var myImages1 = new Array();
myImages1[1] = "beeDraw.jpg";
myImages1[2] = "blackattack.jpeg";
myImages1[3] = "bee1.png";
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
if (rnd == 0) {
        rnd = 1;
}
document.write('<img class="bee" src="' + myImages1[rnd] + '">');
}




</script>
```

Can someone look over this?

Comment: you need to understand the implications of `document.write`

Comment: It's not redirecting you to a new page. You're just replacing everything on the page with the new image.

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to using `document.write` I recommend you use access the DOM of your HTML page and get the image you want by ID. Then set the src equal to your new image.